# Constructing Mediawiki cookies

Tags: php, mediawiki

I'm already using a custom login which I wrote to bridge between my website and Wordpress.

My Mediawiki instance is also on the same domain. However, I've tried looking at how to manage with it for a few hours and I can't figure it out at all. I'm not sure how the AuthPlugin works and I haven't managed to make anything work with it. I can't find sufficient documentation on the subject.

The Login API states [I can construct cookies myself](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aLogin#Construct_cookies). Is there any sort of example or explanation on how the Mediawiki cookies work and how I could generate them?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$wgUser->setCookies();
```

This will automatically create the required cookies once user is authenticated